# Best way to update a cell value and avoid SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame and I want to update a particular cell value (adding a fix number, like 10), like this:

```
df['A'].iloc[0] = df['A'].iloc[0] + 10
```

Which is the best way to achieve this goal avoiding the

```
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df.loc[0, 'A'] = df.loc[0, 'A'] + 10
```